# Can I globally switch to native text rendering in Qt Quick Controls 2?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, text-rendering, qtquickcontrols2

I would like to use native rendering for all the text in my application. For each `Text`, `Label`, etc. element I can do this

```
Text {
    renderType: Text.NativeRendering
}
```

to trigger native rendering. I can also use the software renderer for the whole application:

```
QQuickWindow::setSceneGraphBackend(QSGRendererInterface::Software);
```

However due to some bugs with the software renderer and some performance issues, I would like to avoid that.

Is there a global switch to change the render type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Qt 5.7, you can change the default Qt Quick text render type, but unfortunately only at build time. In order to change the default, you would have to rebuild `libQt5Quick.so` with `QT_QUICK_DEFAULT_TEXT_RENDER_TYPE` set to `NativeRendering`. For more details, see https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/121748/ .

If you have installed Qt using an installer from qt.io, install the source packages using the maintenance tool if you already haven't done so, navigate to `qtdeclarative/src/quick`, run qmake with the define, and build. Something along the lines:

```
cd path/to/Qt/Sources/5.8/qtdeclarative/src/quick
# NOTE: make sure to run qmake from the same/correct Qt installation
path/to/Qt/5.8/<spec>/qmake "DEFINES+=QT_QUICK_DEFAULT_TEXT_RENDER_TYPE=NativeRendering"
make -jN
```

If you have a self-built Qt installation, invoke `make clean` (or if you want to save time, just delete `qquicktext*.o`) before `make` to rebuild the library.

**EDIT: Since Qt 5.10, it is also possible to specify the default text render type in C++ via [`QQuickWindow::setTextRenderType()`](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/qquickwindow.html#setTextRenderType). Just notice to set it before loading the QML content.**

Comment: Am I right to assume that I still need to bring in the various dependencies Qt has (install various -dev packages).

Answer (score 6):

The environment variable `QML_DISABLE_DISTANCEFIELD` controls this.
If you put

```
qputenv("QML_DISABLE_DISTANCEFIELD", "1");
```

at the beginning of your main, you will get a nice and sharp text rendering everywhere.

Source: http://www.kdab.com/~thomas/stuff/distancefield.html

Answer (score 2):

Add this line first in c++ main function : QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL);

Comment: Thanks. Not however that this forces the software renderer.

Comment: oh! i thought you ve got an opengl driver issue , if your texts and labels render well in ur current config , why would you force to native rendering !!!